# How to redirect before 'page does not exist' error in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app that tweets out a show page url every time a post is made (called sub_opp in my app).

So when something gets posted a tweet goes out that includes a link like www.app.com/sub_opp/1

These posts can be canceled by the user.  I'm trying to do a before action on show that says if it's blank, redirect to home and flash a notice but it seems that the id not found beats it to the punch.  Here is my before_action.

```
def validate_opp_open
  sub_opp = SubOpp.find(params[:id])
  if sub_opp.blank?
    redirect_to sub_opps_url, notice: 'Sorry.  This opportunity is no longer available.'
  end
end
```

It gets hung up on the sub_opp = SubOpp.find(params[:id]) line saying it cannot find it, which  makes sense.  Is there any way around this?

HERE IS THE ANSWER

```
 def validate_opp_open
  sub_opp = SubOpp.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if sub_opp.blank?
    redirect_to sub_opps_url, notice: 'Sorry.  This opportunity is no longer available.'
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
sub_opp = SubOpp.find(params[:id])
```

To:

```
sub_opp = SubOpp.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

Comment: i ended up using this answer and it worked.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord provides a facility to check if a record exists:

```
SubOpp.exists?(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is find causes an exception if it doesn't succeed.  You can either catch the exception with `rescue` or use

```
sub_opp = SubOpp.where(:id => params[:id]).first
```

This will produce `nil` when a record is not found.  This is portable between Rails 3 and 4.  @BroiSatse's solution is more elegant, but it will only work on Rails 4.  In Rails 3, you must say

```
sub_opp = SubOpp.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

The `rescue` method will be something like:

```
def validate_opp_open
  sub_opp = SubOpp.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    redirect_to sub_opps_url, notice: 'Sorry.  This opportunity is no longer available.'
end
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time.  this was helpful.  i tried a quick fix with another answer and it worked.  updated code above

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate_opp_open
  unless sub_opp = SubOpp.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to sub_opps_url, notice: 'Sorry.  This opportunity is no longer available.'
  end
end
```

Comment: It's better if you explain *why* your code solves the problem. I'm writing this from the Low Quality Posts review, I'm sure you don't want your name associated with that ;)